# Spring Boot, Slf4j. Как настроить логирование в файл?

Tags: java, spring-boot, логирование, properties, slf4j

Есть веб приложение на буте, у которого пишутся в файл логи slf4j
Как настроить логирование таким образом, чтобы записывались только действия пользователей?
Т.е. нужно, чтобы логи при запуске приложения или ошибках выводились в консоль, но не записывались в файл.

Comment: Сколько писателей у тебя в конфиге?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как любой log4j через файл `log4j.xml`, полная справка есть в официальной документации.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Это если по правильному!

Если по неправильному - то через application.properties или application.yaml.

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging/logging-application-properties/

На вопрос правильности метода, скажу такую вещь - все системные администраторы уже имеют свой собственный настроенный файл xml под разные проекты на серверах которые приводят логирование в правильный единый стандарт. И если не хочешь что-бы сисадмин в тебя кинул камнем, то лучше действовать приближенно к стандарту.

> Как настроить логирование таким образом, чтобы записывались только действия пользователей?

Используй свой собственный фильтр,  и настрой под этот фильтр логирование.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html